# How to send out multiple values from one function?

Tags: c, function

How would I be able to take in, say 2 values, and then output it through one function (which is supposed to do two different types of calculations with the same input values), so that I can output two different values?

So as an example, I have 2 inputs (ex: int a=2, and int b=5), and then I would do some calculations using them (1st one: (a+b)*2, 2nd one: (a-b)/2).  I would normally use two functions for this, but how could I get them to be all under one function and yet still give me two different values?

Edit: I noticed some of the response was to use pointers, but how would I be able to print out multiple answers from the same function in the main program (I actually want to specifically print from the main)?

Comment: read something about passing the arguments using `call by reference` or `call by address.`

Comment: Have you considered using arrays as return types where you can return two different values? If your values are not of same type, returning a `struct` should work?

Comment: @jetuas please do not _edit_ your question to **add** another one. make use of comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
int main()
{
    int a=2, b= 5;
    int result1 =0, result2 =0;

    call_your_func(a,b, &result1 , &result2 );

}

void call_your_func(int p, int q, int * res1, int * res2)
{
//do the first calculcation on a and b, store in *res1

//do the second calculcation on a and b, store in *res2

}
```

If you need to return more number of results, you can cosider using an array for returning values.

EDIT

---

Inside `main()` simply print the values of `result1` and `result2` after calling `call_your_func()`. It will print out the desired results.

Comment: Oh wait, so if I store it in that pointer, I don't have to have a return for "call_your_function"?

Answer (score 2):

```
struct two_results {
    double x;
    double y;
}

struct two_results add_sub(double a, double b) {
    struct two_results ret;
    ret.x = a + b;
    ret.y = a - b;
    return ret;
}
```

This allows you to do

```
struct two_results res1 = add_sub(4, 3);
sum2 = add_sub(6, 3).x;
diff3 = add_sub(12, 3).y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pointers:

```
float value1, value2;
// ...

    your_function(4, 3, &value1, &value2);
// ...



void your_function(int a, int b, float *value1, float *value2)
{
     *value1 = (a+b)*2;
     *value2 = (a+b)/2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say: " but how would I be able to print out multiple answers from the same function?"

```
sprintf(fout,"%d, %d", c, myFunc(a,b,&c));
```

will print the value of c calculated by myFunc, followed by the return value of myFunc.
What you do here, is use the order in which C pushes parameters onto the stack, namely, rightmost pushed first. This rightmost parameter involves executing myFunc, which sets variable c. When myFunc returns, its return value is pushed onto the stack. Then the next argument is pushed, which is c, so the value of c which has just been calculated is pushed onto the stack. Now sprintf is called, which neatly finds two values that it prints.